# How to disable the delete button for the particular row when we are using the table view delegate method commitEditingStyle in Iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Here I need a help from ur side that Im using the tableview delegate method commitEditing sytle to get the delete button for every cell when we swipe.But my problem here is I dont want the delete button for the first row in the tableview and swipe should not work and I dnt have any idea how to implemet this.

Anyone's help will be much appreciated.

Thank You,

Monish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UITableViewCell` has delete style by default. To change that you need to implement `tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:` method in your table view delegate. Return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone` for the 1st row and `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete` for other rows.

Edit: Sorry for incomplete answer. You also need to implement `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` method (something like that):

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return indexPath.row > 0;
}
```

Hope that'll work

Comment: I tried the way u told but the when I swipe the first row the delete button is generating but the action is not performed.I am trying to not generate the delete button when I swipe the first row.can u please suggest me with more idea's?

Answer (score 4):

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
      if(condition check)
          return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;

    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //here your code

     }
}
```